# Should I have one representation of Java model in Spring and Android?

Tags: java, android, spring, maven

I want to write two applications: one in Java Spring (server side) and second in Android.
Server side should collect some sort of information and send it to client when he demands it.

My question is should I (and can I?) share sending entities between this two programs? i.e.: I have two classes User and College. Server has all existing object of User, College and they relationship and when client ask about some User/College server sends it.

The project then should look like:

Main project (contains public class User, public class College).

Spring project (imports via Maven Main project; uses classes User and College).

Android project (imports via Maven Main project; uses classes User and College).

Is this correct? Can I do this is that way?

Comment: Have you implemented a service layer for your server? Do you serve data to clients with JSON or WSDL?

Comment: I'm starting prototyping. Communication between server-client will be with JSON on http

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is should I (and can I?) share sending entities between
>   this two programs?

Yes you can, but there is something you must be careful. The classes which you want to share to your android and server projects(like `User` and `College`) must not include android or non-android imports. So you don't get errors at both side. They will be just wrapper java data classes.

> The project then should look like:
>
> Main project (contains public class User, public class College).
>
> Spring project (imports via Maven Main project; uses classes User and
>   College).
>
> Android project (imports via Maven Main project; uses
>   classes User and College).
>
> Is this correct? Can I do this is that way?

That is correct if you want to share your Main project to your android and server projects. But as I mentioned before, your `Main` project must contain imports both android and server is eligible to work with.

I'm currently using similar approach to yours. I only defined my `JSON` request and response classes at a shared project and included my shared project's jar to both android and server projects.